# JAVA - Matrix color rings

Tags: java, matrix

I need to show a matrix with color in a way that is like a rainbow. 
I found the proper way to "paint" in a system.out.

The matrix should be filled with "0". Those "0" are the ones which should have colours.

But i ran out of ideas of how to implement the method that prints that rainbow.
Here is an image of what I need:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExpDV.png

Any idea?

Thanks!

PD:
I managed to do this but with numbers which i think are more"visually friendly".
This code will fill the matrix with numbers, the external ring would have "1", second ring will have "2", 3rd ring will have "3".... and so on.
This is the code:

```
int counter = mat.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < counter; j++) {
            for (int k = i; k < counter; k++) {

                mat[j][k] += 1;
            }

        }
        counter--;

    }
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague and hard to answer. Please check the [tour] and the [help] sites for information on how to ask better more informative and specific questions. Showing pertinent code and explaining more detail would be where I'd start if I were you.

Comment: Must it be a colored character "o" in the matrix or you doesn't mind filling the entire matrix with color? If it must be an "o" in the matrix, do you want to show the grid lines of the matrix? Try to be more specific, I am sure you can get what you want.

Comment: @user3437460 i just updated the op so its more clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you wanted is an output like this:

```
0000000
0111110
0122210
0123210
0122210
0111110
0000000
```

You can do it with nested loop. I did it without excessive conditional statements with minimal looping. You can do it this way:

```
int r = 7;
int c = 7;

int[][] matrix = new int[r][c];
for(int x=0; x<=r; x++)
    for(int y=0; y<r-x; y++){
        matrix[x][y] = Math.min(x, y);         //Update 1st diagonal half of the matrix
        matrix[r-x-1][c-y-1] = matrix[x][y];   //Update the next half (follow 1st half) 
    }
```

This is probably one of the fastest way to do it. We only need to loop through half of the elements and there are no conditional statements needed. On top of it, you can apply the same concept for colored array.

Comment: **Remarks:**  The above code works for size 0 matrix to size n, where n is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` ***(2147483647)***. Simply test it by changing value of `r` and `c`. Assuming `r` always equals to `c` (Square matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on how big the matrix is. You could make a loop and ad conditional clauses. basically a matrix in programming would be a two-dimensional array. in java:

```
int[][] arr= new int [5][5];
```

this would create a 5 by 5 matrix which you can fill with a inner for-loop

```
for(int i =0; i < 5; i++){
   for(int  a =0; a< 5 ; a++){
     arr[i][a] = something;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Can you look to the op? i just updated it a little